# Where are the tetrahedral voids and octahedral voids located in an FCC?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry

> A crystal is made up of atoms X, Y, and Z. Atoms X are in FCC packing, Y occupy all octahedral voids and Z occupies all the tetrahedral voids. If all the atoms along two body diagonal are removed, find formula of crystal.

Since there are 4 atoms in FCC, number of X=4. Tetrahedral voids occupy twice the number of atoms and octahedral voids occupy half of tetrahedral, so Y=4, and Z=8.

Now how I do proceed from here? I do not know where these voids are located.

Comment: Have you tried searching on google for the structure of an FCC and its voids?

Comment: @Safdar I have but various sources are having various answers so I couldn't confirm

Comment: @Safdar thankyou very much, this gives a perfect explanation. I was wondering if there is a post for the same concept done for CCP or HCP?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/102248/number-of-octahedral-and-tetrahedral-voids-present-in-a-hcp-structure?rq=1

Comment: CCP and FCC are same..